# Storing data uri image in SP list

Tags: 2013, list, image

I'm using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to capture a "screenshot" of the user screen to an html5 canvas element. I'm then using the native **canvas.toDataURL()** which returns something like this

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7
```

But of course the whole screenshot is much longer than that. I then use SP Services to save a message and the "image" in a list. All that is working.

Currently I have a plain text column in my list to hold the image data. To actually see the image the admin has to copy the image data and paste it into a browser like chrome or firefox.

**This is the part that isn't working**

I'd prefer to store the data as an actual img tag. But everytime I try sending the data as an image or putting the image tag into the rich text editor source by hand it doesn't work.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODl...B0UjIQA7" />
```

SharePoint strips out the src and I end up with.

```
<img alt="" />
```

**Here are the questions**

Rather than canvas, to data, to textfield, is there a better way to take a screenshot and send it to a SharePoint list?

How can I store a visual version of the image for my admin to review?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to use a calculated field.

1. Let the actual data get stored in a field
2. Create a calculated field to form the img tag

Comment: Good idea, and I had thought of that, but I didn't see my data uri field as a choice for the calculation. I think it is because it is a multiline textfield. The data uris are over 255 characters so I can't use single line of text.

Comment: Another option is to use workflow for creating the calculated value.